# How to make a conditional query in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-orm

I am trying to filter by a calculated field, where the calculation depends on the value of other fields.

I'm trying to filter by `sales_price` (the calculated field), where `sales_price` is defined like below pseudocode

```
if discount is NULL                                                             
    sales_price = price                                                         
else                                                                            
    sales_price = price - price*discount/100
```

The end goal is to filter `sales_price` by range:

```
filter(sales_price__range=(price_min, price_max))
```

Here is my model:

```
class Product(models.Model):                                                
  price = models.IntegerField()                                             
  discount = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
```

Comment: Have you converted GET params to integers?

Comment: Is price1 lower than price2?

Comment: yes its lower than price2

Comment: i converted to int check above

Comment: How can i even query over sales_price in the that range

Comment: Well you can't, you are filtering on product.price currently I thought that's what you wanted. You can't sort it on sales_price field using filter() as it is a db operation, need to either move that field to db or calculate it using sql.

Comment: i have included one function in my models

Comment: Please don't edit your question with the answer given to you.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'll just point you in the right direction:

### Use `F` expressions in a conditional expression with `When` and `Case`

You want to sort by a value that depends on other values, so let's use a [*F Expression*](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/expressions/#f-expressions) (because `sales_price` depends on other fields) in a [conditional expression](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/conditional-expressions/) (because the final expression depends on whether `discount` is `NULL` or not)

First we construct a `sales_price` value that depends on `discount` and `price`, and annotate our query with it:

```
from django.db.models import When, Case, F, IntegerField

Product.objects.annotate(
     sales_price=Case(
         When(discount__isnull=True, then=F('price')),
         When(discount__isnull=False, then=(F('price') - (F('discount') * F('price')) / 100)),
         output_field=IntegerField(),
     )
)
```

Now with this, you have included a `sales_price` that you can filter with:

```
   Product.objects.annotate(...).filter(sales_price__range=(price_min, price_max)
```

Comment: global name 'IntegerField' is not defined

Comment: cured earlier one..but came up with this one Cannot resolve keyword 'sales_price' into field

Comment: In F('sales_price') is not part of model i think

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104740/discussion-between-adrafe-rinzzler-and-bakkal).

Comment: Can i Annotate it further to get the min and max price out of the queryset

minprice = queryset.annotate(Min('sales_price')) 
maxprice = queryset.annotate(Max('sales_price'))

Comment: I think so, you just need to take into account the order of annotate and filter because it changes the semantics of the query: https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/topics/db/aggregation/#order-of-annotate-and-filter-clauses