# Truly dynamic DateField values in Django

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-models

Some of my app models define date ranges (e.g. of contracts), where the current instance has no fixed end date (i.e. it should always evaluate to today). Setting the `default` parameter on the `end` field –

```
class Contract(models.Model):
    building = models.ForeignKey(Building, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    service = models.ForeignKey(Service, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    begin = models.DateField()
    end = models.DateField(default=datetime.date.today)
```

– will populate the field with a fixed value. A property to work around the problem –

```
class Contract(models.Model):
    building = models.ForeignKey(Building, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    service = models.ForeignKey(Service, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    begin = models.DateField()
    end = models.DateField(blank=True)

    @property
    def get_end(self):
        if not self.end:
            return datetime.date.today()
        return self.end
```

– does not work with querysets. Is there any way to implement a truly dynamic value on the database level using Django's ORM?

Comment: Have `end` be `NULL` and then use `coalesce(end, current_date)` in query.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! Unfortunately, this will not help. My custom `clean()` function contains the following query: `conflicts = Contract.objects.filter(building=building, begin__lte=end, end__gte=begin)`. So the database needs to use a dynamic value for the `end` column to compare against the value of the new row. If there is no technical solution, I will resort to the  tried and tested value of 9999-12-31 as a default, and change this value to the current date when adding a new contract.

Comment: Do you always want the `end` field value to today's time?

Comment: @SunderamDubey Only for the current/ongoing contract (i.e. if there is no fixed date stored in the DB).

Comment: What about `auto_now` and `auto_now_add`?

Answer (score 0):

The best options available for a sudo-dynamic `DateField` are `auto_now` and `auto_now_add` as mentioned in the comments. The former updates the DateField on each `.save()` call and the latter does it at creation ([Django doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateField.auto_now)).

The other option, as mentioned by Adrian, is to set the `end` as `Null` and use a conditional query for your `claen()` function. You can do that either by introducing an if statement or by using `Case()` and `When()`. You can check [this Django doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/conditional-expressions/#case) or see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35668411/how-to-make-a-conditional-query-in-django) for more information.

**Update:** In your case something like this should work:

```
today = datetime.today()

conflicts = Contract.objects.filter(building=building, begin__lte=Case(
...         When(end=Null, then=today), default=end), end__gte=begin)
```

There are also other options for having a dynamic date in your model but not as a `DateField`, which I assume is not what you are looking for nor anything near a 'clean code'.

Comment: Thanks to @SunderamDubey and @Hafezmehr! `auto_now` and `auto_now_add` are too static (as the contracts are never updated, unless they are superseded by a new contract). I fail to see how I could use `Case()` or `When()` to improve the `filter()` statement above, such that the value for `end__gte` will be the current date if the DB field is empty.

Comment: @janeden I added an example for more clarification.

Comment: Thanks for the query example. Unfortunately, it can be used to provide different values for the new entry (which is to be validated). I was looking for some option to return the current day for the `end` field of an existing row in the database whenever `end == Null`. In any case, I built a workaround with 9999-12-31. Thanks again!